# How to trigger caching a file upon loading of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs, full-text-search

I have an inventory item search tool that filters through the huge json file (about 8mb) and if item was found it simply displays all the information regarding that item in a card format.

So now when I load the page, the caching of the file that is 8mb only begins once I start to input characters in the input box of my page.

How can I change this behavior and have the file cached upon loading the page as well as pass the json object to "get_item" function so its ready to match items as soon as I start inputting characters.

I tried using DOMContent.onload and various other onload triggers but no luck :(

Please help.

This is the js code:

````
const match_items = document.getElementById('match_items');

const get_item = async input_text => {
    const inventory_file = await fetch('/static/json/inventory_cookware_2020.json');
    const inventory_json = await inventory_file.json();

    let item_matches = inventory_json.filter(item => {
       const regex = new RegExp(`^${input_text}$`, 'gi');
       return item.match(regex);
    });

    if (input_text.length < 10){
        item_matches = [];
        match_item.innerHTML = '';

    }

    display_item_data(item_matches);
};

function display_item_data(item_matches){

code to display item data...
}
search.addEventListener('input', () => get_item(search.value)); ```





HTML--------------------------------------

   <div id="input_box">
        
        <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search Inventory">

   </div>

<div id="match_item"></div>
````

Answer (score 1):

To have the `fetch` of the JSON file start when the page is first accessed, add the following code to the beginning. This uses an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) to fetch and populate the data when the page first loads. The `search` input is disabled until the file has finished loading.

```
let inventory_json;
const search = document.getElementById('search');
search.addEventListener('input', () => get_item(search.value));

(async () => {
  const inventory = await fetch('/static/json/inventory_cookware_2020.json');
  inventory_json = await inventory_file.json();
  search.disabled = false;
})();

const match_items = document.getElementById('match_items');

const get_item = input_text => {
  // This ensures the function won't run until the AJAX is complete
  // and inventory_json is populated
  if (!is_loaded) {
    return;
  }

  let item_matches = inventory_json.filter(item => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`^${input_text}$`, 'gi');
    return item.match(regex);
  });

  if (input_text.length < 10){
    item_matches = [];
    match_item.innerHTML = '';
  }

  display_item_data(item_matches);
};

HTML
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search Inventory" disabled />
```

Comment: Hello sir,
Is there a way we can add a loader to the "if (!is_loaded) {return;}" where the loader will keep loading until the condition is true

Comment: How about disabling the `search` input until the json file has loaded? This would mean that the `get_item` function won't run before the file has loaded. Let me know and I can update the answer if this is suitable.

Comment: yes that would work, so only thing remaining would be to find a loader solution to display until the get_item function is called

Comment: Answer updated. You can have a CSS loader spinner, for example, displayed when the page loads, then where `search.disabled = false` is, also hide this loader.

Comment: Hello sir,
I think the search.disabled is not working

Comment: i am trying to add a loader but not getting anywhere so far.